# Django error - Pillow is not installed even though it is

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm running Django in a virtual environment on my raspberry pi.
I want to use ImageField, which requires pillow to be installed.
It's installed but if I run python manage.py makemigrations I get the following error: Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
But I have installed Pillow:

```
(DjangoEnv) pi@raspberrypi:~/Django $ pip show pillow
Name: Pillow
Version: 8.3.1
Summary: Python Imaging Library (Fork)
Home-page: https://python-pillow.org
Author: Alex Clark (PIL Fork Author)
Author-email: aclark@python-pillow.org
License: HPND
Location: /home/pi/Django/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Django is in the same location:

```
(DjangoEnv) pi@raspberrypi:~/Django $ pip show django
Name: Django
Version: 3.2.5
Summary: A high-level Python Web framework that encourages rapid development and clean, pragmatic design.
Home-page: https://www.djangoproject.com/
Author: Django Software Foundation
Author-email: foundation@djangoproject.com
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: /home/pi/Django/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

The location should also be in the python path

> > > print(sys.path)
> > > ['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/pi/Django/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

Any Ideas as to what could cause this error?
Thanks

Comment: please share the screen show of the error and also the in which you uses the imagefiedl

Comment: The Error is: Person.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow"

and the models.py contains:
class Person(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')